# ¿ Como poner una imagen de fondo en la barra de navegación?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

```html
<!-- header -->
 <div class="w3_navigation">
  <div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     <div class="logo">
      <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span class="one">G</span>RUPO DUBAIS</a></h1>
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <nav class="cl-effect-1" id="cl-effect-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a class="scroll" href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
       <li><a href="#about" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Venta</a></li>
       <li><a href="#services" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Servicios</a></li>
       <li><a href="#team" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Consultores</a></li>
       <li><a href="#work" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Proyectos</a></li>
       <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Contáctenos</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Hola quiero colocar el logo de la empresa de fondo , el cual es una img de 567x307 a lo largo de la barra del menú pero no he logrado hacerlo.

> Toggle navigation
>
> ## GRUPO DUBAIS

```
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <nav class="cl-effect-1" id="cl-effect-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a class="scroll" href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Venta</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Servicios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#team" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Consultores</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#work" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Proyectos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Contáctenos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega la propiedad "background-img"

ejemplo mediante el atributo style:

```
<div ... style="background-image: url("img.jpg");">
  //resto del codigo
</div>
```

o puedes agregarlo a un css mediante una clase o como desees